# Condition implying rationality of $u^n+v^n$

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

$Given :\ u+v \   is \ rational, \ u^2 + v^2 =1 \ , prove \ v^n + u^n \ is \ rational$.

What I have done so far is proving  that $uv$  is rational by expanding $(u+v)^2$.
I expanded $(u+v)^n$ using binomial expansion but I do not think this is the proper way.

Any hint about how to prove it please?

Comment: Hint: Put $x_n=u^n+v^n$. We have $x_{n+2}-(u+v)x_{n+1}+uvx_n=0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 8):

From the given condition, $(u+v)^2=u^2+v^2+2uv=1+2uv$ is rational implies $uv$ is rational. 
$u^{n+2}+v^{n+2} = (u+v)(u^{n+1}+v^{n+1})-uv(u^n+v^n) $

since $u+v$ and $uv$ are rational, and the statement is true for $n=1,2$, $u^n+v^n$ is rational for all positive integers $n$ by induction.

Comment: This proves the stronger statement that $u+v \in \Bbb Q \text{ and } u^2+v^2 \in \Bbb Q \implies u^n+v^n \in \Bbb Q$, doesn't it?

Comment: @DanielR It does, and it's a nontrivial gain as well since if $\sqrt{u^2 + v^2} \notin \mathbb Q$, you can't simply rescale $u$ and $v$ by a rational number to obtain $\tilde u^2 + \tilde v^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Related to another answer and comment, but perhaps less "magic" and more motivated.

It is given that $u+v$ is rational, and you have proved that $uv$ is rational.  By the binomial theorem,
$$\eqalign{u^n+v^n
  &=(u+v)^n-\binom n1u^{n-1}v-\binom n2u^{n-2}v^2-\cdots
    -\binom n{n-2}u^2v^{n-2}-\binom n{n-1}uv^{n-1}\cr
  &=(u+v)^n-\binom n1(uv)(u^{n-2}+v^{n-2})
    -\binom n2(uv)^2(u^{n-4}+v^{n-4})-\cdots\ .\cr}$$
Now every term on the RHS is either rational by what you know already, or can be assumed rational by induction.

Comment: actually this is what i have done. But how to prove for e.g $(u^{n-2} + v^{n-2})$ is rational?

Comment: Have you studied proof by induction?  How about proof by extended induction (sometimes known as strong induction)?

Comment: @ David i studied proof by induction and i've tried induction on n but still i cant prove it.

Comment: How about extended induction? - Assume that $x^1+y^1$ and $x^2+y^2$ and... and $x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}$ are rational, then you can prove $x^n+y^n$ is rational.